# Excel - How to use Substitute with LEN to replace a positional character with another character?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to replace the second "-" in {Old-Fields-WV} with a ",".
I basically have over 17000 rows and some of these rows contain names of US cities like Old-Fields,Jersey-City along with just one word cities like Boston, Chicago, etc. They are listed as Jersey-City-NJ, Old-Fields-WV in the sheet.

I want to write a formula that only replaces the second "-". The position is third last in all the rows. So I want the names to be read as Jersey-City,NJ or Old-Fields,WV. Is it possible to combine either REPLACE or SUBSTITUTE with LEN as we already know the position?

PS - I'm not finding much info on this anywhere on Google.

Appreciate your time :)

Comment: `=REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-2,1,",")`

Comment: that was easier than I expected. Thank you Scott!

Comment: Or, `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",", ",2)` and better to have a space after comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try using <kbd>SUBSTITUTE()</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",", ",2)
```

---